# Reading filenames from file in python

Tags: python

I'm reading filenames from a ascii file using

```
with open('FilenamesAsciiFile.txt') as f:
    content = f.readlines()
```

Unfortunately when I try to open the file or check wether it exists I get an error:

```
filename = content[0]
print filename
print type(filename)

--> myFile.h5
--> <type 'str'>


import os.path
os.path.isfile(filename)

--> False
```

When I hardcode the string everything is working fine

```
os.path.isfile('myFile.h5')

--> True
```

Is string the wrong input type for that function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to trim '\n' from lines:

```
filename = content[0].strip()
```

Answer (score 5):

The filenames you've read in, contain trailing new line characters.
So your `myFile.h5` is actually `myFile.h5\n`. You'll need to strip the new line before checking it's existence.

```
import os
os.path.isfile(filename.strip())
```

Comment: It works :). Both answers are correct and were really fast. Since I cannot accept both, I will accept one and upvote the other in order to be fair. Thanks a lot!